# Updating database with MySQLdb in Python

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I'm currently trying to make changes to a table using the MySQLdb module with Python, but for some reason the change is not actually occurring. I'm definitely connecting fine, because I can fetch a result so for some reason the update is not working. Code is as follows

```
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="", db="rpi")
cur = db.cursor()
cur.execute("UPDATE heating SET mode = 'change'")

cur.close()
db.close()
```

There is only one row in the table heating. I am not yet running this from a Raspberry Pi.

Why is the database not being updated? I'm not too sure how to get an error with the MySQLdb module, so help with that would be appreciated too, if not required to fix this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to commit your SQL statement after executing it:

```
db.commit()
```

Comment: Thank you, savior!